# AWS Lambda: Failed to restore the function . The function's execution role doesn't have permission to perform this operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I had a perfectly working AWS Lambda function. It processes some data from S3 and then writes some data on S3 and then finishes.

Without updating the code or permissions it now suddenly fails.

When browsing to the lambda function on AWS there is a red bar in the top stating:

> Failed to restore the function "function name". The function's
> execution role doesn't have permission to perform this operation.

There is a button "restore". Upon pressing it I get the error:

> There was a function configuration error. Contact the function’s
> owner.

When I try to test the function the response is as follows:

> Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: Resources for
> the function are being restored. A previous restore operation failed
> with reason. The function's execution role doesn't have permission to
> perform this operation.

I did not change the permissions. The role use to work just fine. I have tried adding extra permissions up to the point of Lambda Full access, but this did not resolve the issue.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved the issue by adding the following permissions.

> "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface"
> "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces"
> "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"

Comment: Can you share what permissions you had? Adding those didn't solve it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, also on a Lambda function that had been working for a very long time but that suddenly would not restore, and I fixed it by copying an inline policy from another function that was working.

So I remember next time:

On the Lambda Function Configuration page, under Permissions, click on the Role Name for that function.

That will open a new tab, within IAM, viewing details for that role.  Click Permissions, then Add Permissions, then Create Inline Policy, click the JSON button, paste in this JSON:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know if all of those permissions are required or if it could be further locked down, but that is what I used.

Then, in the right lower corner, click "Next", and on the next page enter a meaningful name, and then click "Create Policy".  Then, the "Restore" button on the Lambda function page banner worked to restore the function.